# Populating Array Variable with Results of string.match method

Tags: javascript, arrays, match, assign

I am having trouble with some Javascript code regarding populating an array with the results of the string.match method.

Essentially, I am trying to extract an array of strings from a piece of JSON coming from another application.  I have verified that the match method does in fact return a valid array and that my regex expression is accurate.  It is only when trying push these results to its own array that I seem to be running into problems.

The general structure of the code is as follows:

```
var orgSearchDomain = /*JSON STRING*/;
let orgSearchName = '';
let orgId = 0;
var orgAddresses = [];

if (orgSearchDomain.match(/"item":{"id"/g).length = 1) {

orgId = orgSearchDomain.match(/(?<="id":)\d+/)[0];

}
else if (orgSearchDomain.match(/"item":{"id"/g).length > 1){

orgAddresses = new Array(orgSearchDomain.match(/(?<="address":).+?(? 
=,"visible_to)/g).slice(0));
}
```

I've tried declaring orgAddresses within the if-block using var and let without success.  Moving the declaration outside of the if-block using var made some progress where the code no longer crashes but printing any of the properties of OrgAddresses will show that it is still an empty array of 0 length.

I really don't know what I am missing here.  Like I said, just printing properties of

orgSearchDomain.match(/(?<="address":).+?(? =,"visible_to)/g)

will yield correct results; something just seems to be going wrong the assignment to the new array of orgAddresses.

Any help will be much appreciated and please let me know if there is any additional information I may provide.

Comment: use JSON.parse, don't try to regex a JSON

Comment: I would recommend posting an example of the JSON. If its valid JSON, you don't need to use regex and you can use JSON.parse.

Comment: Thank you for the responses so far.  I am going to try to use JSON.parse and see what I can do.

Comment: Alright, so the JSON.parse is certainly something cool that I did not know about it now gives me another way to do this.  However, it will generate the same issue if I try to declare the variable 'orgAddresses' within the if-block.  I guess I can just put it outside but I just don't understand what about the JS syntax creates problems when declaring a variable inside an if statement.